# Changing Opacity with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover, opacity, mouseout

I have 9 items on a grid, I want all items to have 0.5 opacity on every item and only when hovered over should the div/item and everything inside have 1.0 opacicty.

Here is the JS

```
$('.gallery-single').css({ opacity: 0.5 });

$('.gallery-single a').mouseover(function(){
    $('.gallery-single-title', this).css('display', 'block');
        $('.gallery-single', this).css({ opacity: 1 });
});
$('.gallery-single a').mouseout(function(){
    $('.gallery-single-title', this).css('display', 'none');
        $('.gallery-single', this).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="gallery-single">
<a href="#" title="">
<div class="gallery-single-title hide">Some text goes here</div>
<div class="gallery-single-img"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/code/0.jpg" width="300" height="200" /></div>
</a>
</div>
```

All items are at opacity 0.5 when loaded but opacities are not changed when focused.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.gallery-single` is an **ancestor** of the anchor (i.e. it's outside the anchor). The `$(selector, this)` format looks for the selector **within** `this`. Instead, use `.closest()`:

```
$(this).closest('.gallery-single').css(...);
```

---

**Sidenote**: jQuery gives this warning about [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) (also applies to `mouseout`):

> This event type can cause many
>   headaches due to event bubbling. For
>   instance, when the mouse pointer moves
>   over the Inner element in this
>   example, a mouseover event will be
>   sent to that, then trickle up to
>   Outer. This can trigger our bound
>   mouseover handler at inopportune
>   times. See the discussion for
>   .mouseenter() for a useful
>   alternative.

You should use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) (and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)) instead (or the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function which conveniently combines the two).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('.gallery-single a').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('.gallery-single-title').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).closest('.gallery-single').css({ opacity: 1 });
},
function(){
    $(this).closest('.gallery-single-title').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).closest('.gallery-single').css({ opacity: 0.5 });
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/yZL6C/).

Comment: Ah yes this works too, and so doesBox9's method, but I only have one choice to tick who's correct lol

Comment: If both were helpful, *upvote* them both, and **accept** the one that you feel was **most** helpful.